# how to set default theme in twig?

Tags: twig, silex

I use a silex with twig;

I create custom **form_div_layout** and put it in the webroot( for example)

I register TwigService provider like this

```
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../views',
    'twig.options' => array(
        'cache' => __DIR__ . '/../cache/twig',
        'strict_variables' => false
    ),
    'twig.form.templates'=> [WEBROOT . '/form_div_layout.twig']
));
```

but i have an error 
`Twig_Error_Loader: Template "/home/versh/sale/web/form_div_layout.twig" is not defined () in "layout.twig" at line 52.`

how to register theme correctly ?
I know that if i put theme in the **twig.path** it will work, but this is not solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using Twig with namespaces and I think it is the most flexible practice:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
'twig.options' => array(
    'cache' => true,
    'strict_variables' => true,
    'debug' => false,
    'autoescape' => true
   )
));

// set namespace for your application
$app['twig.loader.filesystem']->addPath(WHERE_EVER_YOU_WANT_PATH, 'yourApplication');
```

Now you can render templates using the namespace:

```
return $app['twig']->render('@yourApplication/sample.twig', array());
```

you can define as many namespaces as you need.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add base template `form_div_layout.html.twig` to `twig.form.templates` option too.

```php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
    'twig.options'=>array(
        'cache'     => __DIR__.'/../cache',
    ),
    'twig.form.templates' => array(
        'form_div_layout.html.twig', 
        'theme/form_div_layout.twig'
    ),
));
```